# Firebase 2.0 Send Push Notification From Device to Device - iOS

Tags: push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible using Firebase Messaging to send a push notification from an iOS Device to another iOS Device like you could on parse?

I need it for friend requests and other user interactions. eg send a notification saying "Bob has sent you a friend request"

Thanks!

Comment: Firebase Notifications can be used to send notifications from the Firebase Console (web interface) to users/groups of users. Firebase Cloud Messaging can be used to send messages or notifications to specific users. You will need to run a trusted process for that. To quote the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server): "A full FCM implementation requires both a client implementation and a server implementation. "

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634046/is-it-possible-to-send-pushnotifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-t/37634914#37634914) from a quite authoritative source. :-)