# Does Firebase support direct push notification to other devices?(iOS)

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently making an iOS chat app using Firebase(My app functions just like Whatsapp). I want to know if there is a way for me to send a push notification directly to the other device with out implementing any separate server. I don't have a server to use.

Or is there any other way to notify the user about getting the new message?

Thank You :) Also I'm just a beginner. Just starting to learn about all things iOS.

Comment: Firebase is the server. I think this might help you https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I'v already gone through the documentations. As far as I understand, I need to setup my own App server for push notifications between devices.

Comment: Device-to-device messaging is not supported at the moment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634046/is-it-possible-to-send-pushnotifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-t/37634914#37634914

Comment: Sry my fault totaly missed that you still need to implement your own server. Then Firebase doesn't fill any function really.

Comment: Thank you for the info :). Is there any other way I can do this??