# Can I create subtopics when using Firebase Cloud Messaging (for Android)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently developing an app that uses the new firebase cloud messaging system. Now I see the topic feature of FCM.

I created a topic "news" and want to add sub topics e.g "news/weather" or "news/politics".

Altogether there are about 20 subtopics.

Is this even possible with FCM and is this god practice?

Answer (score 3):

I usually start my topics with a prefix and then the subtopic, separating them with a `_`.

So if I have a sub-topic per user (great for sending user-to-user messages) I end up with:

```
/topics/users_puf
/topics/users_forj9
```

There might be better ways, so I hope others will answer too.

Comment: Yeah I think that this would be the easiest, too. And the features provided by topics are awesome. But the interesting part of it is if this is a god practice and if topics are made for this :)

Comment: They are definitely made for it. I don't think there is a "do it this way" doc from within Google, so it's up to all of us to figure out what works/feels best.

Comment: Having subcategories within news like news_sports and news_culture etc are reasonable uses of topics. The more specific the topic the better, you have an unlimited number of topics so feel free to use them :)

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Arthur. Any ideas on a more suitable separator?

Comment: So normally you don't need to put the tokens on your server anymore, is it right?

Comment: If you use topics, you don't have to keep track of the tokens yourself anymore. That's one of the many advantages of using topics.