# How to send direct message via Firebase from user to user?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am really rookie and need an advice.

I have [read documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/), and as far as i understood if you need send direct message, follow next steps:

1. Make authentification, eventually you get `Firebase TokenId` and
   `userId`
2. Send them to your server side and store it in DB
3. When you are going to send a message you need create `json` and put
   inside `topic` `text` and `resipent userId` so on...
4. Send this `json` via HTTP to your server side
5. When server retrive this `json`, it should use Firebase API to
   create new message bloc `child` with random name in firebase
6. Eventually server have to find recipent user in DB by userId that we get from message.
7. After server will find current recipent user by userId , next we should take `firebase tokenId` In order to sent notification .
8. And send recipent user notification with such data - name of new
   message bloc `child`
9. Recipent will connect to this current bloc and retrive data

It is as i understood this consept, fix me please if smth wrong?

Comment: hello , you can get solution in from my answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any

Comment: @VishalPatoliya yes, according to your answer, can i make conclusion that my point of view is correct?

Comment: 3. When you are going to send a message you need create json and put inside topic text and resipent userId so on...

here is resepient is refresh_token not user_id

Comment: you tried my answer ?

Comment: and if yes than what problems are occurs?

Comment: because this is my research in firebase and like my answer you never got any other solution from any where i gurentee !!

Comment: Just understand, that you send message directly to recipent? Yes? Without your own server?

Comment: according your answer you store all secure data such as "key=" + "your server key", refreshedToken = ""; on the device? Right?

Comment: yes exactly .....

Comment: by refresh token ..

Comment: refresh token is you getting from device when user is login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122281/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-aleksey-timoshchenko).

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko your suggested approach sounds good. You can read how I implemented it in this [Firebase blog post "Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html).

Comment: @VishalPatoliya as I said in my comment to your linked question and answer: embedding the server key in an Android app is a security leak and not recommended. Please don't promote this practice.

Comment: yeah I also followed the awesome guide from @FrankvanPuffelen in the firebase blog, you just need to change the `to` value in the request to the token you get from your first step to send it directly without subscribing to a topic

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen could you halp me to understand, according you post you explain how to send notification. But as far as i get your point i have to put name of user who sent notification and subscribe this user to topic? Actually maybe do you have a full sample?

Comment: @Wilik sorry, but i didn't get your point of view... what you mean `to` value? Maybe do you have a sample?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and one more, it means that if one user is going to sent message to another , server side have to create a topic and send name of topic to recipent and automaticly subscribe him to current topic. And as a result we have topic and 2 users ( sender and recipent) who subscribe on it... is it consept of a chat?

Comment: Creating a topic is a non-action. Topics are auto-created when you send a message or subscribe to them. But you're trying to cover a lot of ground here and comments are not a good format for that. The approach outlined in your question sounds good. If you have a specific problem in one of the steps, post the specific problem as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested approach sounds good. The most important thing to realize is that you require an app server to send a downstream message to a device. Using the database as the communication mechanism between the app and the app server is a popular approach.

You could also use [Cloud Messaging's upstream capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream). But I've never tried that approach, because the database works fine for me and I had little interest in learning yet another protocol (XMPP).

You can read how I implemented it in this Firebase blog post [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html).

Comment: Could you please explain me next thing if i subscrubed to 2 different topic (A and B), it means that i will synchronice with both of them? but how to present it to user separately? in two different chats?

Comment: I would typically just use the notification to show a prompt. When the user clicks that prompt, they come back into the app and you can find their chats there. But all if this is completely up to you, however works for you app.

Comment: And last question) i tryed to find answer in google but without success. Maybe you know. As far as you know when server sending notification client side can hold it in `onMessageReceived()` just if app going in foregroung if app going in backgroung you have to use `bundle` in activity. But question is what are going to be happend if user get notification and discard it? It means that payload data will be lose, right? What do you think about it?