# Delphi Send Device to Device message using firebase

Tags: delphi, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I studied Firebase4Delphi but I just want to implement sending message from one device to the other without the use of PHP, I will like to get user registration id UID without the use of the Firebase console in Delphi, is this possible?

Comment: Device-to-device message sending is not possible without the user of a server. This has been asked a few dozen times already, so I recommend you search for some of those. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any

Comment: Yes Frank but not for Delphi, it is very much known that its NOT SAFE to save API Key but I want to be able to get user registration id given by Firebase without access to firebase console. The questions are based on android while my quest is based on Firebase4Delphi under Delphi

Comment: If you're building on Firebase Cloud Messaging, the answer will always be the same: you cannot send device-to-device messages through FCM. A trusted process is required.

Comment: So Frank I you going to point me to a procedure to get user registration id in Delphi without the use of the Firebase console, I will appreciate that.

Comment: From quickly scanning it looks like Firebase4Delphi is built on Firebase's REST API, which provides no way to authenticate a user (since the REST API is sessionless, it has no concept of a "current user"). To learn more about how to authenticate REST calls, see the Firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#auth

Comment: Have you tried to use the Firebase Open Source Library for Delphi FB4D? github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D or from GetIt