# Firebase push notification with multiple android devices

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, http-post

Iam working on an android project and made a chat application, but cant send notifications. I can post FireBase http from the web interface, but cant find how to do it with android. I have a device register id, project number sender ıd. please help mee .

Comment: have you setup all the things require for firebase in android project?

Comment: Yes i think but i dont know how to use it. can you share a sample code block if you have?

Comment: refer the link 
https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

Comment: yes i know this but actually need to http post. i can send notification with web and firebase console. just cant android devices. its the classic messaging app. i can send message but cant notification. i completed hard part but i couldnt the easy part

Comment: If you haven't already, check this stackoverflow question and the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging . In my chat application, I've used OneSignal to show notifications to the user: https://onesignal.com/ , it's almost free.

Comment: Device to device messaging is not built in to Firebase Cloud Messaging at the moment. To send messages *from* an Android device, you will need to run code on a server. See this [blog post explaining how to do that](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) pr this [explanation from one of the FCM engineers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38432243/).

Comment: i ll try thank u all