# Delphi POST Request to the Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, delphi, curl, firebase-realtime-database, delphi-xe

I’m writing a desktop application using Delphi XE. I would like to request a POST from my application to the Firebase Realtime Database. Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392627/delphi-google-firebase-http

Comment: Have you tried to use the Firebase Open Source Library for Delphi FB4D? github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D or from GetIt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want to interact with the Firebase Realtime Database through REST APIs (e.g. via a POST request), you can use the REST API mode, as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start