# Android Firebase Notification Key - File Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, filenotfoundexception

I tried to generate **notification_key** for **firebase push notification** in **android** using the following code from the firebase doc.

```
public String addNotificationKey(
    String senderId, String userEmail, String registrationId, String idToken)
    throws IOException, JSONException {
URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);

// HTTP request header
con.setRequestProperty("project_id", senderId);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.connect();

// HTTP request
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("operation", "add");
data.put("notification_key_name", userEmail);
data.put("registration_ids", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(registrationId)));
data.put("id_token", idToken);

OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();

// Read the response into a string
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
String responseString = new Scanner(is, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
is.close();

// Parse the JSON string and return the notification key
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseString);
return response.getString("notification_key");}
```

But it returns file not found exception at  `InputStream is = con.getInputStream();` with **response code 400**.

Please help with the possible causes for this.

Comment: Sending push notification from client device is very insecure, don't do that

Comment: Look at this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any/

Comment: Also, 404 is "File not found exception", 400 is "Bad request"

Comment: @DimaRostopira got the message as FileNotFoundException and error code as 400 :)

Comment: Thanks for that url @DimaRostopira

Comment: I'm glad, that it helped you =)