# Sending Push Notification Directly

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I want so send push notification directly using firebase. I don't wanna use any server!
Is it possible?

---

#### To send **Firebase** push notification Android to Android Directly using Firebase

---

Please Help!

Comment: Yes its possible if you have token of particular receiver device.

Comment: There is no way to send direct messages to a device using Firebase Cloud Messaging. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any For ways to accomplish the use-case, see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 0):

> sir firebase is also a server so if you want to send notificaion to every user device or individual device use firebase or use another services like php
>
> without server is not possible

Comment: I will use firebase but not any external server.Just cant finding some resources to study

Comment: You kidding @R.Adnan? Here's everything you're looking for: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/