# Firebase Cloud Messaging API

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using Firebase Cloud Messaging for iOS and Android. Just wondering if its possible to create a web application that has a form whereby we can send push notifications to both platforms at once - assume we know the topics to send to.  (maybe using POST/cURL requests)

Comment: Sending messages with FCM *to* a device requires that your code specify the so-called Server Key. As its name implies this key should only be used on a server or otherwise trusted environment. It is not possible to securely send messages *from* one device directly *to* another device. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716/209103

Comment: The easiest way within Firebase to securely send messages is using Cloud Functions. See this example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Answer (score 0):

yes you can send the push notification in some of the web browsers using firebase integrations (web push notifications)

please go through the following link

```
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/
https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client
```