# Ionic 3 - How to send push notifications from a device using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am very confused on how I can implement push notifications into my ionic project using firebase.

I am trying to implement a push notification sender from the device itself, but currently, the only way I know how to do this is by sending a notification manually via firebase console cloud messaging website.

Is it possible to send push notifications from an Ionic 3 application on one device to other devices on that same application? If so, how should I approach this problem? Could you provide me with links or tutorials on how I could do this?

Comment: Try https://google.com

Comment: @Zoe Why should we make stackoverflow so unfriendly for new users?

Comment: @Zoe I have already tried Google, YouTube, looked at ionic push documentation, firebase documentation and it has not helped much at all, hence why I am asking here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716/209103, https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a push notification over firebase you have to something like this (pseudo code):

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(POST, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

// headers
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + myApplicationFirebaseApiKey);

// data
request.body(mydata);
request.send();
```

`myApplicationFirebaseApiKey` is the api key. You can get it from [console.firebase.google.com](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

`mydata` should contain the target device `to` and `data`:

```
{
  "data" : "UPDATE_AVAILABLE",
  "time_to_live" : 0,
  "to" : "<firebase-device-ID>",
  "priority" : "high"
}
```

As you can see you need the firebase api key. I recommend you to send such requests from your application server. Otherwise you will have to use the api key in your ionic app code and every one can decompile it and steal the key.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info ill give it a try and see if it works

Comment: Did this work? Also how do you get the deviceID?