# Send a notification to another device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

I want to be able to send a notification to another device on android. Currently, on my app, users can upload jobs they want doing and other users can place bids on that job. The user can then accept a bid. When the user has accepted a bid a notification or message needs to be sent to the user who placed the bid. The database that I'm using is Firebase. Each user has an account which they sign in with and a unique ID.

The only things that I have found is sending notifications to my own device.

Comment: you can call webservice from server side for send notification

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716/209103 and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: if you found the answer helpful, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to implement custom notifications with firebase. When the bid is placed, write the user's token and the message in a node in firebase

```
notificationRef.push.setValue(new NotificationModel("bid accepted", firebaseUser().getToken()))
```

Now to send the notification, we will use firebase functions

---

Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Install firebase with node

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Import firebase

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

then send the notification when the notification `node` in `firebase` is written

```
exports.bidNotification = functions.database.ref('/notification/{pushId}').onWrite((event) => {

    const data = event.data;
    console.log('Notification received');

    if(!data.changed()){
        console.log('Nothing changed');
        return;
    }

    const payLoad = {
        notification:{
            title: 'App name',
            body: data.val().message,
            sound: "default"
        }
    };

    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60*60
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(data.val().token, payLoad, options);


});
```

Finally, deploy your functions on firebase using the CLI
Here is more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Enjoy