# Send FCM push from user to user

Tags: android, firebase, post, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I wish to send push messages to specific client from android app. So far it was successful from postman. But how can I translate post to android app?

I need to send post to: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

And this is sample message:

```
{
 "to" : "dLVCgODdwqw:APA91bHz3kb0kyhs0sdf8THHE0DsdfVtHM5Z",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body",
     "title": "Title"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

Comment: *`Hi I wish to send push messages to specific client from android app.`* Yes that is  possible but **[its very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any#comment64284832_38434366)**

Comment: Why is that a bad idea?

Comment: Read comment of  `Frank van Puffelen` that i have added link of that comment in my above comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any#comment64284832_38434366

Comment: You can use `Firebase Cloud Functions` to send notifications from one device to another. That is safe and recommend way to do task like that.