# Push firebase notification to one client

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android application with firebase and i want to send a notification to a specific client from another client .
"cloud messaging" allows me to send a notification to every client has the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging also allows you to send a notification to a single client, as long as you know the FCM token of that client. For example see the section on [sending a message to a token using the Composer in the Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#send_a_test_notification_message), and [sending a message to an individual device using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices), and [sending a message to an individual device using the HTTP REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices).

But FCM does **not** allow directly sending notification *from* once client to another. You will always needs to send the downstream messages from a trusted environment, such as the Composer in the Firebase console, your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.For more on this, see:

- [How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging)
- [How to send device to device messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)
- [Diego's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716/209103)
- probably many more of [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+cloud+message+send+from+android+device+to+another+android+device)