# Unable to send notification message to all the participants of the group in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am creating group chat application in which I want to send notification for newly arrived messages to all the participants of that group when a user send some message in that group.

I have tried storing the device token and sending the them messages

```
private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("Chatts").child("Groups").child(group_name).child("Messages")
            .push()
            .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            );
    input.setText("");



}
```

Here I send the message on click of send button

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: No i dont have any ideas how to do that

Comment: I have group structure like this [Groups----group1-------members_ messages]

Comment: There is no way to securely send an FCM message directly from an Android client. If you want to send FCM notifications, you will need to set up a server for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028340, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716 and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You need an firebase token of the device which receive notification