# Is it possible to send one to one APNS through Google Firebase from ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs) tutorial to send APNS from firebase and what i was able to do is I can send notifications for all devices from google console

What I need is to send a notification to a specific user. Is it possible

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging does not allow you to send messages directly from one device to another device. Downstream messages (messages sent *to* a device) must always be sent from a trusted environment (such as the console, your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions), since they require that you specify the so-called FCM *server* key when sending messages. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028340, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there Any google api's for iOS which will handle APNS using a device token

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Enter notification title and description and click on send message. A popup will come. You need to enter firebase instance id of your device then click plus icon to add token and then click Test. Done

[image]

Comment: Is there any API provided by firebase to handle the same via code