# Firebase Device to Device Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement functionality so that when I click 'Poke' on a person's profile on my App, he/she should get a notification that there is a poke. This should work both in foreground, or when the app is closed. Nothing else is needed. No extra data needs to be passed. Just a simple notification saying that there is a poke.

Comment: Sounds possible, and Firebase Cloud Messaging is the tool for the job. But you can't send messages directly from one device to another, as that would be a security risk. So you'll have to send the messages from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37435750, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279716, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37990140.