# How do I send notification to a specific user in Android using FCM token?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm asking how I can send a notification to a specific user device by using the FCM token. The token is stored in the RealtimeDatabase in Firebase which is structured like this:

```
project-name: {
   users: {
      username: {
         name: "..."
         token: "..."
      }
   }
}
```

This is the code I use to store the token

```
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          String token = task.getResult().getToken();
          saveToken(token);
       }
    }
});
                                                    
private void saveToken(String token) {
   reference.setValue(token);
}
```

where "reference" is the correct pointer to the db.. this works properly.
I want to use the token stored to send a push-notification to the user targeted.
I also have implemented the class MyFirebaseMessagingService but I don't know how to use it to send notification to a specific user using his FCM token that I stored as I posted above.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //here I have code that store the token correctly
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_default)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

So I want to target a specific user by his FCM token and sending him a notification but I can't find a way to do this. Please help me.

Comment: Sending messages **to** a device requires that you specify the FCM server key when calling the FCM API. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. It is **not** possible to directly send messages to a user from within your Android code, as that would be a major abuse vector. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any

Answer (score 2):

To send the notification to a specific user you have to call this API:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

with Authorization:"key=YOUR_FCM_KEY" and Content-Type:"application/json" in header and the request body should be like:

```
{ 
  "to": "FCM Token",
  "priority": "high",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Your Title",
    "text": "Your Text"
  },
  "data": {
    "customId": "02",
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "",
    "alert": "Alert"
  }
}
```

You should call this api from backend (Recommended). You can also call it from your android device,
but

> **Be aware of hijacking your API Key**

For android you can use [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/) for calling API

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
```

and the sample code will be like

```
public static void senPushdNotification(final String body, final String title, final String fcmToken) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject notificationJson = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject();
                notificationJson.put("text", body);
                notificationJson.put("title", title);
                notificationJson.put("priority", "high");
                dataJson.put("customId", "02");
                dataJson.put("badge", 1);
                dataJson.put("alert", "Alert");
                json.put("notification", notificationJson);
                json.put("data", dataJson);
                json.put("to", fcmToken);
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json.toString());
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .header("Authorization", "key=YOUR_FCM_KEY")
                        .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String finalResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.i("TAG", finalResponse);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a backend server to send notifications for specific actions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Although you can use Firebase Realtime Database with Cloud Functions to achieve that also:

https://medium.com/@97preveenraj/firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-with-firebase-realtime-database-7388493cb869

Comment: Ideally, this "backend" will keep a map of userId + FCM Token, so when you know you need to message userId = 10, then you have access to his/her latest FCM Token (that your FirebaseMessagingService should send to the backend when Google calls you back on that Broadcast Receiver with a new Token). Keep in mind the FCM token *can and will* change at random intervals throughout an App's session; it may not change for weeks, but it can suddenly do (if google invalidates it due to a security update or something), so you always have to react to this and update it in your servers.

Comment: Is there a complete tutorial to implement this? It is very difficult