# How to send and receive notifications like social media apps

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have successfully developed a chat app using java and firebase and I am stuck at sending and receiving chat notifications when chatting with a friend who has install my app. i have tried using FCM but to no avail. I have written the code and when i send a message, the friend doesn't receive a notification whether app is in foreground or background as well as no errors are found. please help me out. Below is the code for that class that extends the `FirebaseMessagingService`.

```
@SuppressLint("MissingFirebaseInstanceTokenRefresh")
public class NotifyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull @NotNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

       
        String sent = remoteMessage.getData().get("sent");
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String currentUser = preferences.getString("currentuser", "none");

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(firebaseUser != null && sent.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
            if (!currentUser.equals(user)) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                    sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage);
                }
                else{
                    sendNotification(remoteMessage);

                }
            }



        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void sendOreoNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        assert user != null;
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification(this);
        Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title,body,pendingIntent,defaultSound,icon);

        int i = 0;
        if(j>0){
            i = j;
        }
        oreoNotification.getManager().notify(i, builder.build());
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        assert user != null;
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int i = 0;
        if(j>0){
            i = j;
        }
        notificationManager.notify(i, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused about what your `sendNotification` does. As far as I can tell, the code you shared only **receives** a message from Firebase Cloud Messaging and then displays it in the notification tray of the local device.

None of the code **sends** a message **to** Firebase Cloud Messaging, which is actually only supported from trusted environments (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run) and **not** from within your client-side application code.

You can also [send a message from within the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose), which is great for testing receipt and for targeted messaging campaigns.

To learn more about this, I recommend checking out:

- [How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging)
- [How to send Device to device notification by using FCM without using XMPP or any other script.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any)