# Sending notifications One to One (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with Android and I have two questions that I need an answer for:

**Question 1:** When can you send notifications from one device to another with Firebase without using the server key?

**Question 2:** Are there other ways to send notifications from one to one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sending downstream messages requires your Firebase Cloud Messaging server key and for that reason should be run on a trusted, server-side process. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634046/is-it-possible-to-send-pushnotifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-t

Comment: Thank you, I have already seen that answer but I want to know if Firebase will enable push notifications between users.