# Swift Firebase Send Push Notification

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was wondering how I could send a push notification by code from my app, via Firebase? I am only able to send a push notification from my Firebase Notification-console as of right now, but I would like to figure out how to send one programmatically. Any ideas on where I can find more info on this? Please point me in the right direction! I tried to check out a project on GitHub by Firebase (quickstart), but I have to say that including that project, it's very little information on this. I was lucky to find a tutorial on YouTube that at least allowed me to teach myself how to use remote notifications.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sending push notifications programmatically with Firebase Cloud Messaging, currently requires that you run your message-sending code on a server. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37634914/209103 and the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server)

Answer (score 4):

You can, Firebase (formally Cloud Messaging) provides REST API to send push notifications, checkout the following documentation,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

You have to construct the payload, generate **Server API Key** from Firebase Console and send http request to Firebase endpoint (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

And if you are looking for any library, here is the one which works

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgcmserverjar.htm

it will send push to GCM server, but it works with Firebase too(we are currently using it)

i don't currently find any official SDK provided by firebase to send push notifications

Comment: Would this allow a 'user to user' push notification feature? I am currently developing a chat-application that uses JSQMessagesViewController and I need to send a push notification for each message that is not read in the application. I know Backendless has this feature, but I am not willing to use both Firebase and Backendless (store user info in two different backends).. Basically I want to listen for incoming entries in /Recent in Firebase - and then display a push notification.

Comment: Yes as long as you know the other user push token and store server api key in your client app, yes it's possible!

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, would you mind telling me a bit more in detail on how I would approach this? :) Do I have to run the server on a VPS?

Comment: It's now possible with Google Cloud Functions. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106374/144088