# How to add notification with Firebase IOS chat?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have implemented firebase chat in iOS app, and it is working fine, I am trying to implement if any user send message other will get notification if he is not online. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Sending device to device messages is not possible with the Firebase Cloud Messaging API at the moment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634046/is-it-possible-to-send-pushnotifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-t

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't offers sending push notifications for now.
You can use third party services to send push notifications. One of the very famous is [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/). It is very easy to add into your project and configure to your needs.