# iOS Firebase - Send push notification from device to device

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was working with parse server for my projects, It was a pretty good server with all features. Now I'm moving my server to Firebase. Firebase do have push notification service. But I'm not able to find any concrete solution for sending **Push Notification from Device to Device** just like parse do.

Is it possible to implement it without having any backend service? Apparently, parse server provide a fully functional push notification solution. PFPush & PFInstallation help us to implement that easily.

Is there any alternative solution for Firebase Push Notification?

Comment: You are looking for "Local Notifications".

Comment: I don't think so firebase supports device to device notification ... you can use [oneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) for notification with firebase may be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589514/push-notifications-with-firebase-and-swift/40592604#40592604