# Firebase device to device chat with notification

Tags: android, firebase

I want to develop a one-to-one chat in android by [using Firebase](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-real-time-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial.html). By using 
crazzyhit code one-to-one chat is working.

But device to device push notification is not working. I googled device to device notification, but all are showing about sending notification from firebase console. Can anyone give some device to device chat notification tips?

Comment: Recommending off-site tutorials is off-topic on Stack Overflow. That said: you could do worse than starting with the approach I outlined here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html. Note that this requires you have an app server, since [Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't support sending messages directly from one device to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634046/is-it-possible-to-send-pushnotifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-t).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you can try [OnseSignal](https://onesignal.com/). It lets you sending push notifications from device to device.

Comment: Ya I tried.I got the api key and all...But Coding part they didn't give

Answer (score 0):

You have to create php webservices which will let you send notifications to specific devices on behalf of device tocken.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check [FireChat](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/) to make Person to Person Chat app.